# Iphone and Android mobile development - Getting started

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I'm a web developer in ASP.NET, C# and looking to start some mobile development. I'm aware Apple uses Objective C and Android uses Java, is there a way to create an app for both platforms or do I need to buy a Mac and some books on objective c and Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://phonegap.com/ or http://www.appcelerator.com/platform to write cross-platform apps.

Answer (score 0):

Rumour has it that Delphi XE3 (Due to come out soon) can be compiled onto Apple, Android, Windows 8 etc.etc. so if you can hold out a little longer that should be good!

For now, you are better using a mac (with XCode) to program for IOS or OSX as Apple is very particular and you need certificates for devices, projects, development and distribution etc.etc.etc.

Android i believe you have a bit more play with, but at the moment it is 2 seperate languages. Check out the DEV centres:
https://developer.apple.com
developer.android.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to create apps for both platforms, especially if you know web technologies : [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and others.

But like specified [in the doc](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/ios-builds), you will most probably need an actual mac if you want to build to iOS

Although there are [workarounds](http://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/iapproach-mobile-development-made-elegant/deploying-to-iphone-without-a-mac-with-an-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) or [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform). Haven't tried them myself, though. But with those tools you could build for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a .Net, C# developer, i recommend you to use Mono for Android, it comes with cost but will save you time and easy to deploy
http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid

Answer (score 0):

The best way to be truly cross-platform is to develop for the web.  I would include this in your consideration of development strategies, in addition to PhoneGap and Titanium, as Peter mentioned.  You do not have as much access to core OS features, but that is improving all the time (see http://mobilehtml5.org/).  Whether or not this is feasible depends on what you are trying to accomplish.